# Angular 1 what a service can do and factory can't do or what a factory can do and service can't

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I read many stackoverflows posts and articles, all they say is angular service returns an instance whereas angular factory returns anything you want.
What I want to know is, what is the thing than Service can do and factory can't do or vice-versa.
If you say anything you can do with service can also be done with factory then why did Angular provided two things (Service, factory).

Comment: Do you even Google?

Comment: @Lansana  I googled but didn’t find any answers. Seems like you know answer. Can you answer ?

Comment: @Vikas if read my question carefully I asked about what is the thing you can achieve with service and not with factory. I didn’t asked about difference.

Comment: @D7thename did you even care to go through the answer provided in that post?

Answer (score 0):

One of the main differences is in a factory you can run some initialization code before the factory object is returned.